# C# 6 Null Conditional Operator for Method Fails

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

The following (C# Interactive) compiles but blows up.  Not sure what I'm missing...

```
class Test { public Func<object> GetSomething = null; }
var t = new Test();
var result = t?.GetSomething();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "blows up"?

Comment: NRE at run time; exactly what I don't expect - I expect the null conditional operator to just set result to null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it does!

By your code, `t` is not `null`, so `?.` is redundant.

But `t.GetSomething` isn't. That's what's throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

What you're looking for is this:

```
var result = t.GetSomething?.Invoke();
```

To see how the new C# 6 features are implemented, take a look at [my article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/).

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the way this operator works.

```
var result = t?.GetSomething();
```

Here `t?.` means "if `t` is null, stop right here and return null; otherwise, dereference `t` and retrieve member `GetSomething`.

Now, you're not checking anything on `GetSomething`. Instead, you could do:

```
var result = t?.GetSomething?.Invoke();
```